# Disable input field when selecting another in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a text field and a drop down select as follows.

```
<section class="popupBody"  data-ng-controller="PostController">
 <form>
    <input class="form-control col-sm-2" type="text" ng-model="buyer_cname" placeholder="Enter Buyer's Company Name" >

    <label style="text-align:center;">Or,</label>

    <select ng-model="buyer_cname_dropdown" required>
             <option  value="">Select the Buyer From Drop Down</option>
             <option value="test1">Test1</option>
             <option value="test2">Test2</option>
             <option value="test3">Test3</option>
    </select>
 </form>
</section>
```

Controller

```
  function PostController($scope, $http, $cookieStore) {
      var token = $cookieStore.get('token');
      var conId = $cookieStore.get('Cont_Id');
      var exId = $cookieStore.get('ex_Id');
      $scope.submit_pt = function() {
          var buyer_name = $scope.buyer_cname;
          var buyer_cname = $scope.buyer_cname_dropdown;  
          var seller_name = $scope.seller_cname;
          var seller_cname = $scope.seller_cname_dropdown; 
          var description = $scope.description;
          var amount = $scope.amount;
          amount = (amount*100);
          var p_types = $scope.post_typess;
          $scope.post_transaction = [];
          var post_tran = "http://www.smple.mobi/account/post_member_transaction.html?contactid="+conId+"&exchangeid="+exId+"&token="+token+"&buyerid=21458&seller_name=eBarter%20Master%20Account&desc="+description+"&amount="+amount+"&sellerid=2951";
    $http.get(post_tran)
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.post_transaction = response;
            console.log($scope.post_transaction);
            $('.posted').show();
            $('.posted').html('Transaction Posted');
            $('.posted').delay(4000).fadeOut();
                $scope.description = "";
            });
    }
}
```

Both the text field and the select will be returning the same value, so i want an option to disable the select when user enters the name in the text field and vice versa. User shouldn't be able to enter the name in the text field and select the another from drop down. Your thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like that. It is plain Javascript, but should do the Job, if i get it right:

```js
function input(object){
    if (object.id=="text"){
       if (object.value!=""){
         document.getElementById("select").style.visibility="hidden";
         document.getElementById("select").removeAttribute("required"); 
         document.getElementById("select").setAttribute("disabled","");  
         document.getElementById("lable").style.visibility="hidden";  
       }else{
         document.getElementById("select").style.visibility="visible";  
         document.getElementById("lable").style.visibility="visible";  
         document.getElementById("select").setAttribute("required","");  
         document.getElementById("select").removeAttribute("disabled");  
       }
     }else{
       if (object.value!=""){
         document.getElementById("text").style.visibility="hidden";  
         document.getElementById("lable").style.visibility="hidden";  
         document.getElementById("text").removeAttribute("required");  
         document.getElementById("text").setAttribute("disabled","");  
       }else{
         document.getElementById("text").style.visibility="visible";  
         document.getElementById("text").setAttribute("required","");  
         document.getElementById("lable").style.visibility="visible";  
         document.getElementById("text").removeAttribute("disabled");  
       }  
     }
    
  }
```

```html
<form>
    <input class="form-control col-sm-2" id="text" type="text" ng-model="buyer_cname" placeholder="Enter Buyer's Company Name" onkeyup="input(this)" required>

    <label style="text-align:center;" id="lable">Or,</label>

    <select ng-model="buyer_cname_dropdown" id="select" onchange="input(this)" required>
             <option  value="">Select the Buyer From Drop Down</option>
             <option value="test1">Test1</option>
             <option value="test2">Test2</option>
             <option value="test3">Test3</option>
    </select>
 </form>
```